# #{optional.get()} throws javax.el.BeanELResolver can not access a member of class com.google.common.base.Present with modifiers "public"

Tags: jsf, guava, el, option-type

I am trying to use Google Guava Optional in EL but get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javax.el.BeanELResolver can not access a member of class com.google.common.base.Present with modifiers "public"

Here is the code:

```
<f:param name="locale" value="#{somebean.getUserLocale().get()}"/>
```

Is it not possible?